# Gravatar inside Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, gravatar

I have managed to produce the string output of the gravatar image associated with the email address but struggling to actually show the image...

This is inside of User.php within the Model file.

```
public function getGravatarAttribute()
    {
        $hash = md5(strtolower(trim($this->attributes['email'])));
        return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/$hash";
    }
```

Showing the output using this:

```
<li>{{ Auth::user()->gravatar }}</li>
```

I need to now turn this into the actual Gravatar image...but a tad stuck

Comment: Did you try actually using the HTML image element?

Comment: But would the source be?

Comment: `{{ Auth::user()->gravatar }}` actually returns the correct url, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the URL as `src` for an image element:

```
<img src="{{ Auth::user()->gravatar }}"/>
```

Comment: Just shows looking at code for too long frazzles your brain... works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with img property using bootstrap.

```
<a href="{{ route('profile_path',$user->username) }}">
<img class="media-object" src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ md5($user->email) }}" alt="{{$currentUser->username}}">
</a>
```